# How to make a rails server wide object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redditkit

I am using the [RedditKit gem](https://github.com/samsymons/RedditKit.rb) and in order to access certain elements, I need to send a request to reddit api to create a ["client" object](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/redditkit/RedditKit/Client). Below is my current logic:

```
## application_controller
before_action :redditkit_login

private

def redditkit_login
  @client = RedditKit::Client.new ENV["reddit_username"], ENV["reddit_password"]
end
```

As you can see in my logic here, before EVERY REQUEST, I am subsequently making a new client object and then using that everywhere.

**My question is, how do I only make one client object which can be used to serve ALL requests from anywhere?**

My motive behind this is speed. For every request to server, I am making a new request to reddit and then responding to the original request. I want to have the client object readily available at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options. A simple one would be to create a `config/initializers/reddit_client.rb` file and put in there:

```
  RedditClient = RedditKit::Client.new ENV.fetch("reddit_username"), ENV("reddit_password")
```

(note I switched to `ENV.fetch` because it will error if the key is not found, which can be helpful).

You could also rename the file as `app/models/reddit_client.rb`. Although it's not really a model, that folder is also autoloaded so it should work as well.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Site speed increase by 10x :)